# Advanced Search filter error?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I don't know if this is by design or just a special case, but when applying the following search filters `score:0 is:answer closed:no` the `closed:no` causes the results to show only questions, despite the `is:answer`.

Like I said, I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I'm misinterpreting some of the filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), as only questions can get closed, not answers. If you hover your mouse over the `closed:yes` options under Advanced Search Tips the tooltip says:

> Search questions that are closed (yes)
>
> Search questions that are not closed (no)

Comment: I assumed that an answer would be considered a "child" to a question, therefore allowing an answer query access to this field. Thank you for the clarification.